# The output of my code is incorrect, and I need some help. (File input/output)

Tags: c++

For homework we have to input a text file provided for us:

```
Giselle Robinson Accounting
5600 5 30
450 9
75 1.5
```

and this is the expected output:

```
Name: Giselle Robinson, Department: Accounting
Monthly Gross Salary: $5600.00, Monthly Bonus: 5.00%, Taxes: 30.00%
Paycheck: $4116.00

Distance Traveled: 450.00 miles, Traveling Time: 9.00 hours
Average Speed: 50.00 miles per hour

Number of Coffee Cups Sold: 75, Cost: $1.50 per cup
Sales Amount = $112.50
```

My output :

```
Name: Giselle Robinson, Department: Accounting
Monthly Gross Salary: $5600.00, Monthly Bonus: 5.00%, Taxes: 30.00%
Paycheck: $4116.00
Distance Traveled: 450.00 miles, Traveling Time: 9.00 hours
Average Speed: 50.00 miles per hour
Number of Coffee Cups Sold: 1, Cost: $0.50 per cup
Sales Amount: $0.50
```

My issue is with the number of coffee cups sold. I doesn't pull the value of 75 for cups sold and skips to the price of the coffee cup "1.50" , and separates it. What am I doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {   
   ifstream inFile;
   ofstream outFile;

   string firstName;
   string lastName;
   string departmentName;

   double grossSalary, bonus, taxes, salaryAndBonus, paycheck, distance, travelTime, avgSpeed, coffeeCost, salesAmount;
   int coffeeSold;
   
   inFile.open("inData.txt");
   outFile.open("outData.txt");   
   outFile << fixed << showpoint;
   outFile << setprecision(2);
   
   // Input file information 
   inFile >> firstName >> lastName >> departmentName;
   outFile << "Name: " << firstName <<" " << lastName << ", " << "Department: " << departmentName << endl;
   
   // Calculating monthly salary   
   inFile >> grossSalary >> bonus >> taxes;
   outFile << "Monthly Gross Salary: $" << grossSalary << ", " << "Monthly Bonus: " << bonus << "%, " << "Taxes: " << taxes << "%" << endl;  
   salaryAndBonus = grossSalary + (bonus/100 * grossSalary);
   paycheck = salaryAndBonus - (taxes/100 * salaryAndBonus); 
   outFile << "Paycheck: $" << paycheck << endl;
   
   // Calculating Average Speed
   inFile >> distance >> travelTime >> avgSpeed;
   outFile << "Distance Traveled: " << distance << " miles, " << "Traveling Time: " << travelTime << " hours" << endl;   
   avgSpeed = distance / travelTime;  
   outFile << "Average Speed: " << avgSpeed << " miles per hour" << endl;
   
   // Calculating number of coffee cups sold 
   inFile >> coffeeSold >> coffeeCost >> salesAmount;
   outFile << "Number of Coffee Cups Sold: " << coffeeSold << ", " << "Cost: $" << coffeeCost << " per cup" << endl;  
   salesAmount = coffeeSold * coffeeCost;  
   outFile << "Sales Amount: $" << salesAmount << endl;
   
   inFile.close();
   outFile.close();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do `infile >> salesAmount`?

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run this code, what did you see? This is what a debugger is for and if you don't know how to use it, this is a good opportunity to learn running your program one line at a time in a debugger, monitoring all variables and their values as they change and analysing your program's logic and execution. It should be possible for you to use your debugger to find all simple problems in this and all future programs you write, all by yourself. Do you know how to use a debugger? Knowing how to effectively use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer.

Comment: Explain `>> avgSpeed` to your cat. Which item in the input corresponds to the average speed?

Comment: make your life easier by seperating reading numbers from the file from calculations and output. In this code I'd expect to see some custom struct with a `<<` and `>>` overload.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik the debugger doesn't come up with anything incorrect....

Comment: @SarahO -- The debugger has no idea what your program was designed to do.  Only you know that.  The debugger's job is for you to be able to single-step through your program, where you set breakpoints, watch variables, etc., and then it is for you to determine if what you are seeing is correct or not.  For example, if you were asked to write a program to add two numbers, but instead it subtracts two numbers, the debugger cannot read your mind and know your program is wrong.

Comment: Funny this (for me :-). Just by looking at *"Cups Sold: 1, Cost: $0.50 per cup"* I could guess that you read the value `1.5` using an `int` for the `1` and floating point for the `.5`. So out of sync with the input!  This is what a little bit of experience does to you ("been there, done that"  :-)

Comment: hey @n.m I deleted the >> avgSpeed and it worked. Thanks :)

Comment: @SarahO You repeat the same error yet another time with `salesAmount` – though this time it doesn't hurt as you're at the end of the file anyway. It will break, though, as soon as you continue reading more data...

Answer (score 2):

What you read is

```
inFile >> firstName >> lastName >> departmentName;
inFile >> grossSalary >> bonus >> taxes;
inFile >> distance >> travelTime >> avgSpeed;
inFile >> coffeeSold >> coffeeCost >> salesAmount;
```

The input is:

```
Giselle Robinson Accounting
5600 5 30
450 9
75 1.5
```

Lets make a list:

```
firstName       Giselle 
lastName        Robinson 
departmentName  Accounting
grossSalary     5600 
bonus           5
taxes           30
distance        450
travelTime      9
avgSpeed        75
coffeeSold      1.5
coffeeCost
salesAmount
```

Thats only the reading part, I didnt look at the calculations yet, because already reading the input is wrong. As mentioned in a comment, `avgSpeed` should not be read from the file. You are actually calcualting already via `avgSpeed = distance / travelTime;` and by this overwriting the value read from the file. Thats 1 missing value. I hope you can figure out the other by yourself.

Once you got that straight I would suggest you to introduce some structure to your code. There are many different ways. I choose one, not necessarily the best, but its simple and already helps to make the code more readable...

Use one custom struct for the input:

```
 struct input_from_the_file {
      std::string firstName;
      std::string lastName; 
      std::string departmentName;
      int grossSalary;
      //...
 };
```

Write code to read this from the file. Look at the four lines at the top. Its not more complicated than that. In your code it does look complicated, because those four lines are scattered all around. Better keep stuff that belongs together together. If you have the code to read from the file (and not more) test the hell out of it until you are sure that it is correct.

Then you can define a second struct for the output:

```
  struct output {
      std::string firstName;
      std::string lastName; 
      std::string departmentName;
      // ...
      double avgSpeed; // <- not in the input but has to be calculated !
      // ...
  };
```

And a function to transform between them:

```
 output transform(const input_from_the_file& inp) { ... }
```

And eventually the code to write `output` to the console.

For bonus points you can take a look at how to write overloads for `<<` and `>>`, and `transform` should actually be a constructor of `output`.

Answer (score -1):

Here is your code with required same change at 3 certain positions.

Your requirement was just to add '\n' after these number of lines:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <string>
 #include <iomanip>

 using namespace std;

 int main() {

 ifstream inFile;
 ofstream outFile;


 string firstName;
 string lastName;
 string departmentName;

 double grossSalary, bonus, taxes, salaryAndBonus, paycheck, distance, travelTime, avgSpeed, coffeeCost, salesAmount;

 int coffeeSold;


 inFile.open("inData.txt");
 outFile.open("outData.txt");


 outFile << setprecision(2);
 outFile << fixed << showpoint;


 // Input file information
 inFile >> firstName >> lastName >> departmentName;


 outFile << "Name: " << firstName <<" " << lastName << ", " << "Department: " << departmentName << endl;


 // Calculating monthly salary

 inFile >> grossSalary >> bonus >> taxes;
 outFile << "Monthly Gross Salary: $" << grossSalary << ", " << "Monthly Bonus: " << bonus << "%, " << "Taxes: " << taxes << "%" << endl;

 salaryAndBonus = grossSalary + (bonus/100 * grossSalary);

 paycheck = salaryAndBonus - (taxes/100 * salaryAndBonus);
 outFile << "Paycheck: $" << paycheck <<"\n"<< endl;

 // Calculating Average Speed

 inFile >> distance >> travelTime >> avgSpeed;
 outFile << "Distance Traveled: " << distance << " miles, " << "Traveling Time: " << travelTime << " hours" << endl;

 avgSpeed = distance / travelTime;

 outFile << "Average Speed: " << avgSpeed << " miles per hour" <<"\n"<< endl;

 // Calculating number of coffee cups sold


 inFile >> coffeeSold >> coffeeCost >> salesAmount;

 outFile << "Number of Coffee Cups Sold: " << coffeeSold << ", " << "Cost: $" <<                          
 coffeeCost << " per cup" << endl;

 salesAmount = coffeeSold * coffeeCost;

 outFile << "Sales Amount: $" << salesAmount <<"\n"<< endl;

 inFile.close();
 outFile.close();
 // Write your main here
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: sorry, I think you didnt understand the issue in the code. The problem is not just missing line breaks

Comment: maybe you missed that, the line breaks are from an edit I made (because the original formatting was all scrambled), I asked OP to confirm whether the line breaks are right, but I think they didnt reply yet. I assume the difference in line breaks in expected vs actual is only my fault

Comment: I think there is something missing, Need more clearance and information what is accurately needed?..

Comment: look at the output and desired output more carefully. There is more difference than line breaks.